# Bootstrap modal window ctrl+A not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Currently we are using bootstrap modal window. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> the content of the modal window is not selected.

In IE11 the content of the modal window and its parent screen are selected, in versions less than IE 10, the modal content is not selected.

Is there any way to control the selection of the modal pop up content?

Comment: For me, CTRL + A selects nothing at all in IE. In Firefox, Chrome and Edge the whole content of the page is selected, not only the PopUp.